# Minikube installation on Debian 9

Tags: kubernetes

I've installed docker on Debian 9.3 and created a swarm using 4 computers.
Now I am trying to install Kubernetes locally and am having some trouble getting things to work.

```
$ uname -a
Linux tma 4.9.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.65-3 (2017-12-03) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I'm trying to follow this guide:
https://kubernetes.io/docs/getting-started-guides/minikube/

I want to use Deb9 since that is what I use in our lab.
I am using KVM as the hypervisor.
Has anyone installed Kubernetes locally via Minikube successfully?

I get the following error: when I issue kubectl cluster-info as sudo and non-sudo

> $kubectl cluster-info
>   Kubernetes master is running at localhost:8080 To further debug and diagnose cluster problems, use kubectl cluster-info dump. The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I have Minikube running on Debian.

I can reproduce your error if I don't have anything running. Most probably your cluster didn't start, you'll need to debug more.

This is a great Debian 9 + Minikube resource: https://medium.com/linagora-engineering/install-k8s-minikube-on-top-of-kvm-on-debian-9-9cd5b646063c